# Translating Internet vernacular + 'disorder' into Latin

Tags: english-to-latin-translation

Newbie to Latin here.  I thought it might be amusing to translate web slang into Latin, but this raised a few questions.
If the accuracy is lacking, please let me know how!

#### LOLUMADCUZUBAD?

> Turbati estis quia vos imperitis?

*Are you upset because you are inexperienced?*

1. Why does the meaning of the first phrase change radically when the sentence is split?

   E.g. `Turbati estis? Quia vos imperitis?` vs `Turbati estis quia vos imperitis?`

---

Additionally, what is the best translation for 'disorganization' or 'disorder' (e.g. in the sense of personal/work chaos or disorganzation?

#### We fear no disorganization

> Non timēmus inordinationem

*We fear no disorder*, or *Do not fear disorder*

1. Which is it?
2. Assuming my translation isn't a fault (big if, I know): why do multiple software translators confuse `timēmus` (indicative active present-tense first-person plural) with the imperative?

Comment: Just a quick note: "why do multiple software translators confuse...?" Because no real time was spent trying to make them better. Auto-tagging for Latin has been around many years, but online translators are not content with spending the time or money to develop the necessary AI.

Comment: Interesting topic! It also might be amusing to make acronyms of your translations since it's a very Roman thing to do that is also common with internet slang.

Comment: I removed the last question, because it has already been answered [here](https://latin.stackexchange.com/questions/1180/roman-uses-of-diacritical-marks).

Comment: Was there an answer here earlier, or is that just my imagination?